# Does memory size of variables in JAVA depend on Java Virtual Machine?

Tags: java, memory-management, jvm

Do the variables have varying memory sizes depending upon the JVM?

Comment: @BrianRoach It depends on what size we are talking about (size of an int = 32 bits vs. memory taken by an object = xxx bytes).

Comment: @assylias - Fair point, it's unclear if he means the actual internal storage or not. That's not the way I read it, obviously. But a reference value is always the same size ;) an object isn't a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.

For example, objects almost certainly use up more memory on a 64bit JVM than on a 32bit JVM.

The "logical size" of primitive types such as int (which is always 32bit) is fixed by the Java specification, though.

Comment: It seems to me that the accepted answer on the question Brian Roach linked to contradicts this. But I'm not an expert.

Comment: @11684 They are not talking about the same size.

Comment: Yes, there are two ways to approach this rather vague question. I hope to have fixed it in my edit.

Comment: Primitive sizes set by spec. Can be found here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @xagyg - they are, but how that is managed *internally* would be a different matter. A 64bit `long` on a 32bit JVM is different than a 64bit `long` on a 64 bit JVM internally. The OP's question is vague in that regard.